# Is it better to flag or delete my own question if it is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reputation

I created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822849/how-can-you-a-prove-jvms-environment-is-too-slow-to-run-it-adequately

I feel it is a duplicate of: [JVM benchmarking application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386873/jvm-benchmarking-application)

I would rather flag it as a duplicate, than just delete it.  I think that may help people find it in the future.  However, I am worried flagging myself will hurt my reputation or something like that.

Comment: Duplicates aren't inherently bad, or would hurt your reputation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with duplicates- In fact, they can be useful signposts to the original question. If you feel your question helps make the original more easily discovered, via different wording for example, dupe close it. If you don't feel your question will be a useful signpost, feel free to delete.

Comment: Though it looks you're asking for a 3rd party resource which is _off-topic_.

Comment: If nothing else, I made it sound less like a software recommendation.

Comment: This makes me wonder. Why would you think it is OK to create a duplicated question about a duplicated article?

Comment: @AndreCanilho Well, it's a sign post... I am helping people navigate. :)

Answer (score 2):

The question you feel it is a duplicate of is not an appropriate question on SO.  It's a product recommendation question.

We don't need more copies of a question that's not appropriate for the site; just delete it.

Comment: Well, if nothing else, i made it sounds little less like a software rec.